# Two windows opening when page loads

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, windows

In a Windows application, I'm creating two forms, named `Form1` and `Configuration_Form`. First, I'm loading the `Configuration_Form`. In this form, I check the connection to a txt file. If the txt file has some data, it means that it will load `Form1`.
Otherwise Configuration_Form won't load anything.

Now I have a problem, suppose the txt file has some data, then it means that it's going to load `Form1` and open another empty form. I want to show only the `Form1`, not the empty form. How can I block that empty form?

This is my partial code:

```
      public partial class Configuration_Form : Form
{
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    public Configuration_Form()
    {
        StreamReader tr = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + "config.txt");

        string config = tr.ReadToEnd();
        if (config.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty) == "")
        {
            tr.Close();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        else
        {
            form.Show();
        }
    }
    ///////////////////////////
   private void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((txtIP.Text != "") && (txtdatabase.Text != "") && (txtuser.Text != "") && (txtpass.Text != ""))
            {
                StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + "config.txt");
                sr.Write(Convert.ToString((txtIP.Text) + ";" + (txtport.Text) + ";" + (txtdatabase.Text) + ";" + (txtuser.Text) + ";" + (txtpass.Text)));
                sr.WriteLine();
                sr.Close();
                this.Hide();
                form.Show();

            }
            else
            {
                DialogResult msg = MessageBox.Show("All are mandatory fileds!", "SBS-BIO-CONFIG Administrator", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(msg) == true)
                {
                    this.Show();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("'" + e1.Message + "'");
        }
    }
```

Here is the `Form1` code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    MySqlConnection con;
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    MySqlDataAdapter DA;
    MySqlDataReader DR;
    DataSet DSS;

    #region Form_Load

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Here is my `Program.cs` code:

```
   namespace BIO_PUNCH_UPDATE
   {
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Configuration_Form());
    }
}
}
```

Please, help me to fix this error.

Comment: are you loading data on `Form_Load`?

Comment: What do you mean by an additional empty form? Is `Form1` opening on `btn_submit_Click` or on the constructor?

Comment: btn_submit_Click is not a matter. suppose config.text doesn't have any value means i load data from button click event. Now you consider config.text having some value, First it go to Configuration_Form and check config.text. It's having some value so go to form1 In this time open two windows one id Form1 and another is empty form. How can i block the empty form..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need to load one of the forms depending on the config data. If so then here is the code:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form form;

        StreamReader tr = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + "config.txt");

        string config = tr.ReadToEnd();
        tr.Close();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(config))
        {
            form = new Configuration_Form();
        }
        else
        {
            form = new Form1();
        }

        Application.Run(form);
    }
```

Also if you need config data in one of the forms you can pass config string as constructor parameter.